# Can I use a for loop counter where there is a number in the property names in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I have this html code but I have 20 products and the only code that changes in them are the `image1` `caption1` `product1` etc.

I'm new to Django and not sure if this can be done with a for loop using a counter or if it can be done with an `{% include ___ with ____ %}`? Or can it be done with Python code? I'm even newer to Python and wouldn't be sure how to do that.

I tried a for loop counter but it said i couldnt do `{% image page.image{{ forloop.counter }} fill... %}` as it expects the `%}` before the `{{ }}`

```
 {# Product1 #}
        <div class="document product-card">
            <div class="w3-card-4 w3-margin w3-white" data-aos="fade-down">
                {% image page.image1 fill-150x150-c100 %}
                <div class="w3-container">

                </div>
                <hr>
                <p id="caption">{{ page.caption1 }}</p>
                {% for download in page.product1.all %}
                    {% with doc=download.product1 %}
                        <div class="download product-info">
                            <a href="{{ doc.url }}" class="smooth-over-button noDecoration">
                                <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
                                <p class="btn-txt">{{ doc.title }}</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    {% endwith %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The with statement inside your loop is doing a cache, so the doc variable that you are creating will always point to your first product.

I suggest that you drop the with completely and instead reference the document with the full name.

Also, it feels like there could be a logic error somewhere else, or at least some poorly named variables, since you are referencing a product1 in page and then a product1 in download.

If you are new to python but have experience with another languages, is better if you treat the for statement as a foreach, as python doesn’t have the traditional for logic.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
page.image|add:forloop.counter
page.caption|add:forloop.counter
page.product|add:forloop.counter
```

Comment: It just wasnt picking up the name of the variable